# PostFix/Dovecot new installation on Centos6

Tags: postfix, email-server, centos6, dovecot

I have installed Postfix and Dovecot on my server. It seems to be mostly working - I can send mail from my account to a remote account no problem.

My problem is receiving it. When I send an email from a remote host, I can see the email is being received in the folder:

```
/root/mail/new/
```

However dovecot appears to be looking for the email in:

```
/home/webmaster/mail/.imap
```

How do I make these the same in the config files? I guess the dovecot one is the correct one as it has the username in the path.

My main.cf has:

```
home_mailbox = mail/
```

and dovecot.conf has:

```
mail_location = maildir:~/mail
```

Thanks for looking.